# Include GROUP BY in query 1 of a UNION, instead of two queries UNIONed to get fill rates/row counts by category id

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table of example data:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable 
(
    CategoryID varchar(10), --Non-Unique
    ArbitraryColumnName varchar(10), --Non-Unique
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable (CategoryID, ArbitraryColumnName)
VALUES
    ('1', '14578123'),
    ('2', NULL),
    ('1', '13402348'),
    ('4', '12302354'),
    ('4', NULL),
    ('5', '12678912')
```

| CategoryID | ArbitraryColumnName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 14578123 |
| 2 | NULL |
| 1 | 13402348 |
| 4 | 12302354 |
| 4 | NULL |
| 5 | 12678912 |

I am trying to get the counts for all of the categories together, and the separates categories, in the same table.  Here is my query to do so:

```
SELECT
    CAST('TempTable' AS varchar(55)) AS TableName
    ,CAST('ArbitraryColumnName' AS varchar(55)) AS FieldName
    ,CAST('All CategoryIDs' AS varchar(55)) CategoryID
    ,COUNT(*) AS Table_RowCount
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.ArbitraryColumnName IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Field_NonNullCount
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT a.ArbitraryColumnName) AS Field_DistinctCount
    ,CAST(100 * AVG(CASE WHEN a.ArbitraryColumnName IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS 
numeric(10,2)) AS Field_FillRate
FROM #TempTable a

UNION

SELECT
    CAST('TempTable' AS varchar(55)) AS TableName
    ,CAST('ArbitraryColumnName' AS varchar(55)) AS FieldName
    ,CAST(a.CategoryID AS varchar(55)) GroupID
    ,COUNT(*) AS Table_RowCount
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.ArbitraryColumnName IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Field_NonNullCount
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT a.ArbitraryColumnName) AS Field_DistinctCount
    ,CAST(100 * AVG(CASE WHEN a.ArbitraryColumnName IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS 
numeric(10,2)) AS Field_FillRate
FROM #TempTable a
GROUP BY a.CategoryID
```

Results:

| TableName | FieldName | CategoryID | Table_RowCount | Field_NonNullCount | Field_DistinctCount | Field_FillRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TempTable | ArbitraryColumnName | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 100.00 |
| TempTable | ArbitraryColumnName | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0.00 |
| TempTable | ArbitraryColumnName | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 50.00 |
| TempTable | ArbitraryColumnName | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 100.00 |
| TempTable | ArbitraryColumnName | All CategoryIDs | 6 | 4 | 4 | 66.67 |

What is the best way to combine the queries of the UNION to provide the same results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can write the above Union query as in this [DBFIDDLE_DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/5fzJdYXK)

Which gives the same output as above :

```
SELECT
    CAST('TempTable' AS varchar(55)) AS TableName,
    CAST('ArbitraryColumnName' AS varchar(55)) AS FieldName,
    COALESCE(CAST(a.CategoryID AS varchar(55)), 'All CategoryIDs') AS CategoryID,
    COUNT(*) AS Table_RowCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.ArbitraryColumnName IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Field_NonNullCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.ArbitraryColumnName) AS Field_DistinctCount,
    CAST(100 * AVG(CASE WHEN a.ArbitraryColumnName IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS numeric(10,2)) AS Field_FillRate
FROM #TempTable a
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((a.CategoryID), ());
```

Output :

| TableName | FieldName | CategoryID | Table_RowCount | Field_NonNullCount | Field_DistinctCount | Field_FillRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TempTable | ArbitraryColumnName | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 100.00 |
| TempTable | ArbitraryColumnName | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0.00 |
| TempTable | ArbitraryColumnName | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 50.00 |
| TempTable | ArbitraryColumnName | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 100.00 |
| TempTable | ArbitraryColumnName | All CategoryIDs | 6 | 4 | 4 | 66.67 |

Comment: Wow, that is a wonderful solution, thank you.  I didn't know GROUP BY GROUPING SETS was a thing.  Looks like I have lots more to study.  Thank you again!